# Install sqlalchemy on the learning machine

Tags: sqlalchemy, conda

I need to install sqlalchemy.

```
conda install sqlalchemy
```

After installing it, instead of output c, it gives me an address as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkevd.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO; question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} sqlalchemy
```